# before_save method #1 if method #2 == 0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model, callback

If a user retroactively creates a challenge he already `accomplished` then how can `before_save` check if `days_left_challenged == 0`?

### challenge.rb

```
  before_save :days_left_challenged_sets_deadline

  def days_left_challenged_sets_deadline
    if self.days_left_challenged == 0
      self.accomplished = true
    end
  end

  def days_left_challenged
    self.days_challenged - ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date| 
      committed_wdays.include? date.wday
    end + self.missed_days
  end
```

With this code right now `accomplished` remains `nil` even if the user creates a challenge that would have `days_left_challenged == 0`.

Comment: Are you sure in the case you're testing that `days_left_unchallenged` returns zero? Additionally are you sure that function is running and your record is actually saved?

Comment: So it enters the `if self.days_left_challenged == 0`, sets `accomplished` to `true` but it still ends up as `null` in the database?

Comment: What are you expecting the `date_started.to_date`  to be? Past or Future?

Comment: For debugging purposes, change the if statement in `days_left_challenged_sets_deadline` to
`self.accomplished = days_left_challenged == 0 ? true : false` and see if that results in `accomplished` being set to `false` or if it's still `nil`.

Comment: You might also try overriding `def days_left_challenged=`, it's an alternate approach to `before_save`.

Comment: And is it still NULL in the database, or is it false?

Comment: Cool. And btdubs, `NULL` is the SQL equivalent of Ruby's `nil`. I just assumed you were using a relational database, and my bet was on sqlite or postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needed to be `days_left_challenged <= 0` because I didn't realize that it didn't stop at 0. Rookie mistake.

Comment: I almost suggested that at one point, but assumed days_challenged minus the value returned by the count block plus the missed_days was such that it would always be zero or greater. Glad you figured it out.